# json how to edit items user information with python

Tags: python, json

so if i had a json storing user info eg

```
 
{
    "joe": [
        {
            "name": "joe",
            "age": "28",
            "height": "",
            "Password": ""
        }
    ] }
```

how would change or append information so i can add info or change it using python so for example i get a input of 177 for the height how would i add it to data["joe"][0]["height"] using python

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the value to it

```
data = {"joe": [{"name": "joe", "age": "28", "height": "", "Password": ""}]}
data["joe"][0]["height"] = 177
print(data)
# {'joe': [{'name': 'joe', 'age': '28', 'height': 177, 'Password': ''}]}
```

---

Your format is strange, the idea of a name key is nice, but the array is strange idea, it doesn't seem to add anything

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json.loads()` to transform the JSON data to a dictionary, and then modify the dictionary as you normally would:

```py
import json

json_data = """{
    "joe": [
        {
            "name": "joe",
            "age": "28",
            "height": "",
            "Password": ""
        }
    ] }"""

data_as_dictionary = json.loads(json_data)
data_as_dictionary['joe'][0]['height'] = input()
print(data_as_dictionary)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the array from the json. Using name as a key is not really a good idea, what if there is 2 same names?

Json file:

```
{"joe": [{"name": "joe", "age": "28", "height": "", "Password": "" }]}
```

Python code:

```
from json import load, dump

with open('json_file', 'r') as f:
   users = load(f)
   # with load() you store json data into a dictionary, you can check by printing type()

users['joe'][0]['height'] = 177

with open('json_file', 'w') as f:
   dump(users, f)
   # with dump() you are storing new data into the json file
```

Edit:
Btw you will probably see both load and loads, the s in load stands for "string" and it is used to load json data from a string, and load is used for loading json data from a file for example. The same goes for dump and dumps